# Endnotes do not be superscript and add a space

Tags: formatting, endnotes

See my picture.

[image]

**Also I want to add a space between the number and note**. Besides writing `\endnote{ hello}`, are there any formal way?

This is my source code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{[\arabic{endnote}]}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
As traffic in Macao is a problem\endnote{ hello}, we want to do the project to find out the relationship of traffic among different sites\endnote{world}.

\theendnotes
other references...

\end{document}
```

Comment: From page 3 of the manual, you should redefine `\@makeentext{<note>}`.  Unfortunately, this macro is neither defined nor used in the actual style file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `endnotes` package uses `\makeenmark` for typesetting the footnote mark both in the text and in the endnotes.

We can take advantage of the fact that the endnotes are printed in a group to redefine the command locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}

% end note marker = superscripted number in brackets
\renewcommand\makeenmark{\textsuperscript{[\theenmark]}}

% in the endnotes, we change it without `\textsuperscript`, adding a space
\patchcmd{\theendnotes}
  {\makeatletter}
  {\makeatletter\renewcommand\makeenmark{[\theenmark] }}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

As traffic in Macao is a problem\endnote{hello}, we want to do the project
to find out the relationship of traffic among different sites\endnote{world}.

\theendnotes

other references...

\end{document}
```

[image]