# Convert endnote superscripts to parenthetical numbers

Tags: footnotes, superscripts, endnotes

I have a manuscript that I want to submit to a journal that requires that the numbers referencing endnotes be in-line numbers in parentheses, rather than superscripts:

[image: LaTeX output with parenthetical non-superscript and superscript]

Is there a simple way to redefine `\endnote` (or `\footnote`) to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you need endnotes, right?

Comment: Yes--the journal wants endnotes.

Comment: Ok then this is a duplicate of [Endnotes do not be superscript and add a space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99984). (I.e., the code there can be used to do exactly what you want.)

Comment: Do note that in some subjects, you don't need to worry about things like this in order to submit a paper, but only if it is accepted.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn.  I had glanced at that answer, but viewed it as asking how to change the formatting only in the endnote.  I didn't notice that both number formats were defined.

Comment: @cfr, yes, and they're going to have put up with other departures from specifications in my submission, but I thought I'd at least make this change if it was easy.  And it is!

Comment: Yes, this can be considered a duplicate, in the sense that the answer to that question can easily be used to answer mine.  That was what I intended to convey with my earlier comment, @AlanMunn.  I'm currently using that solution, so the question is answered, even though it wasn't obvious to me at first that that other question provided the answer to mine.

Comment: @mars yes I know. That's an automatic comment made when a vote to close is made. :)