# Formatting endnotes resp. references

Tags: endnotes

I refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100001/113820 formatting endnotes.
How to get endnotes left aligned (without indent of first numbered line with [1], [2] etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the redefinition of `\makeenmark` to produce a left flush label in the indentation space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}

% end note marker = superscripted number in brackets
\renewcommand\makeenmark{\textsuperscript{[\theenmark]}}

% in the endnotes, we change it without `\textsuperscript`, adding a space
\patchcmd{\theendnotes}
  {\makeatletter}
  {\makeatletter\renewcommand\makeenmark{\makebox[\parindent][l]{[\theenmark]}}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

As traffic in Macao is a problem\endnote{hello}, we want to do the project
to find out the relationship of traffic among different sites\endnote{world}.

Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}
Again\endnote{x}

\theendnotes


\end{document}
```

[image]